# Cross-account AWS resource access with AWS CDK using Identity-based cross account usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cdk-typescript

I have got two accounts in which I have two different stack one, account A and account B. Account B has got resource S3 bucket in which I wanna read and write using lambda of account A.

I have tried following steps mentioned [here](https://www.luminis.eu/blog/cloud-en/cross-account-aws-resource-access-with-aws-cdk/).

While configuring S3 stack(Account A). I have below codes to do the same.

````
      assumedBy: new ArnPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::accountB:root'),
      roleName: 'cross-account-role'
    });

    //add statement to allow assumerole action for this account
    const assumeStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      actions: ["sts:AssumeRole"],
      resources: [role.roleArn]
    });
    //assumeStatement.addActions('sts:AssumeRole')

    //add under the principal policy
    role.addToPrincipalPolicy(assumeStatement);

    //add statement to allow reading and putting into s3 bucket in original account
    const resourceStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      resources: ['arn:aws:s3:::bucketName-testing'],
      actions: [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ]
    });


    //add as new policy
    role.addToPolicy(resourceStatement);```
````

Assigning a role to lambda

```
lambda.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
        resources: [roleArn], //roleArn as created in s3 stack
        actions: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    }))
```

Lambda Function Definition (Account B)

```
export default async (event: any, context: any) => {
  const filename = 'xyz.json'


  const STS_PARAMS = {
    RoleArn: roleArn, // created in first step
    RoleSessionName: 'can-be-anything'
  }


  const stsRole = await stsClient.send(new AssumeRoleCommand(STS_PARAMS));

  const credentials = {
    accessKeyId: stsRole.Credentials!.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: stsRole.Credentials!.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: stsRole.Credentials!.SessionToken,
  }

// @ts-ignore
  const s3Client = new S3Client({ region, credentials })
const payload: PutObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket,
    Key: filename,
    Body: event.body,
  }
  

  try {
    //Upload to s3 bucket and return success
    const putObject = new PutObjectCommand(payload)
    const response = await s3Client.send(putObject)
    return {
      success: true,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Using the above methods , I am getting error as mentioned below i.e Access Denied.

```
{"errorType":"AccessDenied","errorMessage":"Access Denied","trace":["AccessDenied: Access Denied","    at throwDefaultError (/var/task/index.js: 8116: 24)","    at /var/task/index.js: 8126: 39","    at de_PutObjectCommandError (/var/task/index.js: 26260: 14)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues: 96: 5)","    at async /var/task/index.js: 1465: 24","    at async /var/task/index.js: 5608: 22","    at async /var/task/index.js: 2905: 42","    at async /var/task/index.js: 32277: 22","    at async /var/task/index.js: 1719: 26","    at async /var/task/index.js: 66269: 22"]}
```